# Add Members to Yammer Group Programatically

Tags: rest, yammer

I am trying to add members to Yammer group programmatically using the path **/Group_Settings/Process_Additions/** with authentication token

for e.g. 
https://www.yammer.com/network.org.uk/group_settings/process_additions/1234567.json

"id": "1234567",
"invites[emails][addresses]": "UserName@Network.org.uk",
"auto_add_invitees":true

It's giving error (404) Not found

Has anyone tried this approach recently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

process_additions is an undocumented api. You'd want to impersonate the user as described in this [blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/israelo/archive/2015/07/31/yammer-restful-api-how-to-bulk-add-members-to-a-group.aspx) post